# SSMS toolbar and ribbon buttons repeating several times

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2016, ssms-18

I'm using SSMS 18 and after I installed SSIS and SSRS on my machine I noticed that pretty much every button in every menu in SSMS is repeated several times as shown in the pictures:

[image]

[image]

I've tried reinstalling and repairing but the issue persists.

Has anyone else encountered this issue? I've found some threads but none of the solutions seems to work.

Comment: Looks like possible registry corruption, maybe try searching for menu entry names as registry key values and see if there's any key duplication going on.

Comment: @Stu I couldn't find menu entry names in the Registery (I don't have much experience with Registery at all) do you know where I can look precisely?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I also couldn't find SqlStudio.bin anywhere on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Go to tools > Customize

Click the Commands tab

Click "Reset All"

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g040O.png)

Comment: Tried that, didn't work.